# FFmpeg low CPU usage

Tags: video, cpu, ffmpeg, video-conversion

I'm using FFmpeg to convert a number of files from MP4(H264 & AC3) to MP4(H264 & AAC) using the command `ffmpeg -i in.mp4 -c:v copy -c:a aac out.mp4`

I have a 4 core CPU with hyper-threading that shows around 15% usage when doing the conversion. The files are located on an SSD, and disk activity is around 3MB/s, so disk does not seem to be a bottleneck.

When the encoding starts the CPU hits its maximum frequency, but I have not noticed the load on any of the cores to go over about 50%.

Does FFmpeg make poor use of multiple cores? Is there any way to make the encode faster?

Comment: Run several `ffmpeg` processes at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

The only thing you're encoding is audio, and most audio encoding libraries in existence are single-threaded. This is most likely because audio encoding is already blazing fast as a single-threaded application (when compared to video encoding anyway), and it doesn't use too much memory so it's actually feasible to encode each file using a single thread and just start up as many separate processes as necessary to fully saturate the CPU. Factor in the fact that multi-threading also doesn't necessarily result in linear performance improvements and you probably have the reason why the developers of most audio encoders don't think multi-threading is a high priority. I know only of two audio encoders that implement multi-threading - LAME MT for MP3 and [pflac](https://github.com/peplin/pflac) for FLAC - and both are separate modifications that aren't part of the main codebases of the projects they derived from.

As for your CPU usage, with hyper-threading you have 8 logical cores and one eight of 100% is 12.5% which isn't too far from your 15% utilisation figure. I'm not really sure why you system isn't showing a 100% load on any of the cores, perhaps the OS is moving the process between cores to even out the load or something like that.

If you need to encode a large number of files you might want to consider writing a script that spins up multiple FFmpeg processes to encode multiple files at the same time. I have very little scripting/programming experience but I know of an open source tool that applies the same logic for image optimisation: [picopt](https://github.com/ajslater/picopt/). So if you need a pointer on how to do it in Python you could take a look at picopt's source code.

Answer (score 0):

check `ffmpeg -hwaccels`

from https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html

> `-hwaccels` List all hardware acceleration methods supported in this build of ffmpeg.
>
> ```
> -hwaccel_device[:stream_specifier] hwaccel_device (input,per-stream)
> Select a device to use for hardware acceleration.
>
> This option only makes sense when the -hwaccel option is also specified. Its exact meaning depends on the specific hardware
> ```
>
> acceleration method chosen.
>
> ```
> vdpau
> For VDPAU, this option specifies the X11 display/screen to use. If this option is not specified, the value of the DISPLAY environment
> ```
>
> variable is used
>
> ```
> dxva2
> For DXVA2, this option should contain the number of the display adapter to use. If this option is not specified, the default adapter
> ```
>
> is used.
>
> ```
> qsv
> For QSV, this option corresponds to the values of MFX_IMPL_* . Allowed values are:
>
> auto
> sw
> hw
> auto_any
> hw_any
> hw2
> hw3
> hw4
> ```

Comment: Those are video decoding accelerators. OP is copying the video, so no decode operation involved.

Comment: I thought he encodes audio from ac3 to aac